# Swift - No value associated with key CodingKeys

Tags: ios, json, swift

I run this error when I tried to parse a JSON response returned by an open API:

> keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "name", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"name\", intValue: nil) (\"name\").", underlyingError: nil))

This happens in the following line of code:
`let decodedWeatherData = try decoder.decode(WeatherData.self, from: data)`
And here's the part of decoding codes:

```
func parseWeatherJSON(data: Data) {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    
    do {
        let decodedWeatherData = try decoder.decode(WeatherData.self, from: data)
        let id = decodedWeatherData.weather[0].id
        let temp = decodedWeatherData.main.temp
        let name = decodedWeatherData.name
        
        let weather = WeatherModel(conditionId: id, temperature: temp, cityName: name)
        print(weather.tempStr)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Here's my JSON response:

```
{
  "coord": {
    "lon": 121.4692,
    "lat": 31.2323
  },
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 800,
      "main": "Clear",
      "description": "clear sky",
      "icon": "01n"
    }
  ],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 25.48,
    "feels_like": 26.36,
    "temp_min": 23.86,
    "temp_max": 26.95,
    "pressure": 1011,
    "humidity": 87
  },
  "visibility": 10000,
  "wind": {
    "speed": 3,
    "deg": 140
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 0
  },
  "dt": 1695067161,
  "sys": {
    "type": 2,
    "id": 2043475,
    "country": "CN",
    "sunrise": 1695073210,
    "sunset": 1695117382
  },
  "timezone": 28800,
  "id": 1796231,
  "name": "Shanghai Municipality",
  "cod": 200
}
```

My structure of `WeatherData`:

```
struct WeatherData: Codable {
    let name: String
    let main: Main
    let weather: [Weather]
}

struct Main: Codable {
    let temp: Double
}

struct Weather: Codable {
    let description: String
    let id: Int
}
```

It seems my structure correspond to the JSON response. I don't know why the decoding was failed and  CodingKeys can't be associated

Comment: Are you sure the JSON is correct? Try printing out `String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)`.

Comment: have you tried `var name: String?` in case the property is optional? Similarly for `Main?` and `[Weather]?`

Comment: Actually this can only happen if you use the `forecast` API rather than the `weather` API

Comment: Replace `print(error)` with `print("Error: \(error) while trying to decode: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)")`, it's a good thing so print the actual receive JSON with your request as the one you posted is coming from... ? As it could be a missing param in request making it send errors (Errors in JSON, HTML errors, etc.), wrong URL, etc... and show us the real JSON you try to decode as suggested by @vadian it could be a wrong url/API...

Answer (score 0):

The JSON listed is valid, but the error indicated that the JSON, at that time, provided by the Server was missing the key `name`, so the error arise.

- **This works well**

```
struct WeatherData: Codable {
    let name: String
    let main: Main
    let weather: [Weather]
}

struct Main: Codable {
    let temp: Double
}

struct Weather: Codable {
    let description: String
    let id: Int
}

func parseWeatherJSON(data: Data) {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    
    do {
        let decodedWeatherData = try decoder.decode(WeatherData.self, from: data)
        print(decodedWeatherData)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

let jsonString = """
{
  "coord": {
    "lon": 121.4692,
    "lat": 31.2323
  },
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 800,
      "main": "Clear",
      "description": "clear sky",
      "icon": "01n"
    }
  ],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 25.48,
    "feels_like": 26.36,
    "temp_min": 23.86,
    "temp_max": 26.95,
    "pressure": 1011,
    "humidity": 87
  },
  "visibility": 10000,
  "wind": {
    "speed": 3,
    "deg": 140
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 0
  },
  "dt": 1695067161,
  "sys": {
    "type": 2,
    "id": 2043475,
    "country": "CN",
    "sunrise": 1695073210,
    "sunset": 1695117382
  },
  "timezone": 28800,
  "id": 1796231,
  "name": "Shanghai Municipality",
  "cod": 200
}
"""


if let data = jsonString.data(using: .utf8) {
    parseWeatherJSON(data: data)
}
```

- **This dose not work**

Change one of JSON's key `name` to `nam`, the error is the same, so that is the problem.

```
let jsonString = """
{
  ···
  "nam": "Shanghai Municipality",
  ···
}
```

---

### Solution

1. Make true the Server provide the right format JSON all the time, which means what is the must and what is the optional.
2. Make variable `name` from type `String` to `String?`

Answer (score -1):

The decoding is correct. The issue is in the data which you are getting from the network, there may be some other characters other than JSON, so it is throwing this type of error. I prepared data from the string just to demonstrate.

```
let json = """
{
  "coord": {
    "lon": 121.4692,
    "lat": 31.2323
  },
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 800,
      "main": "Clear",
      "description": "clear sky",
      "icon": "01n"
    }
  ],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 25.48,
    "feels_like": 26.36,
    "temp_min": 23.86,
    "temp_max": 26.95,
    "pressure": 1011,
    "humidity": 87
  },
  "visibility": 10000,
  "wind": {
    "speed": 3,
    "deg": 140
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 0
  },
  "dt": 1695067161,
  "sys": {
    "type": 2,
    "id": 2043475,
    "country": "CN",
    "sunrise": 1695073210,
    "sunset": 1695117382
  },
  "timezone": 28800,
  "id": 1796231,
  "name": "Shanghai Municipality",
  "cod": 200
}
"""
let data = json.data(using: .utf8)
```